# Host IIS Server applications on the internet

Tags: iis, hosting, windows-server

I know this may be straight forward and may have already been asked but I have been unable to get proper online articles on this or atleast I don't know how to ask google. so here's a scenerio.

1. I have a Windows Server which will be hosting applications.
2. These applications need to be accessible over the internet.

***NOTE I'm aware I can just port forward and users can access the apps via a public IP. This isn't how I want it.***

3. Users should be able to access my apps through [www.my-apps.com](http://www.my-apps.com). This domain will be registered with e.g. Godaddy, etc.

How do I go on about this ? No matter how complicated this maybe, I am ready to get my hands as dirty as possible to implement this.

Comment: Ask Google what is DNS.

Comment: I know what DNS is

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the hosts file of the server hosting your site to point to the local machine's IP when visiting the [www.my-apps.com](http://www.my-apps.com) domain should do it.

1. Open the IIS Manager, in the Connections pane of IIS, expand the Sites and select the website which you want to access via IP address.
2. Click on Bindings link and you will see current bindings of that website.
3. Click on Add button to add a new binding, On the Add Site Binding window, keep website Type as http. Select an IP address from the drop-down menu upon which you want to bind the website, then type [www.my-apps.com](http://www.my-apps.com) in the Host name, click OK and then Close.
4. open this file: c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.
5. Add the following entry to the file: `IP Address        www.my-apps.com`
6. Save to save your changes